# Is there a coordinate-free Dirac equation?

Tags: dirac-equation

Dirac equation is always written with indices. Is there any way to write it down without any indices ABSTRACT or not, and without coordinates,basis vectors etc..?

Comment: Always? $/ \!\!\!\partial$ .

Comment: How can you have a differential equation for a function on spacetime without having any coordinates to express where you are in spacetime?

Comment: No, you don’t need indices. Just write it out using $t,x,y,z$ derivatives.

Comment: There is, although doing it carefully requires introduction of spinor bundles. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dirac+operator for example.

Comment: This is still in component form exactly the opposite of what I want. It's not about being invariant under component of frame transformations , it's about being completely coordinateless as I specified in the question.

Comment: G smith_ using vectors not coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Writing out $\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ is really no different than writing anything that looks like an inner product (for example, the Laplacian). If you're concerned that the indices don't make the frame-independence obvious, then just write it as a four-vector dot product:
$$
(i\gamma\cdot\partial - m)\psi = 0.
$$

I'm not saying that this notation is usual, or even that you will find it anywhere, but it seems no different to me than writing, say, $\nabla \times \nabla f = 0$ or $\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi = -\rho$.

Comment: Ok so why don't you write it down exactly as you did the last line if it's all the same..